# linespace function in matlab

Tags: matlab

i have question related to linespace  ,as   definition of linespace from matlab tutorials,it is function which  generates  linearly spaced points,but  what does means  linearly spaced points?for example following code linspace(5,10,4) Generates 4 linearly spaced points between 5 and 10.so it means that between  these posint there exist  linear  relationship?like

```
y=a*x+b?
```

because if it is  equally spaced points ,then it would be

```
5   6.25    7.5 8.75
```

so i want to  master in this function and clarify everything related this  function for using next  time.thanks a lot of

Comment: The path to enlightenment is paved with the stones of practice.  The easy seduction of a ride aboard the carriage called 'tell me the answer' will lead you astray.  In short: why are you asking a question which you can answer for yourself by trying a few simple examples, then a few more complicated ones.  Matlab is, among other things, a great environment for interactive experimentation.

Comment: this question is not  about matlab,but  about function,i want to clarify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify - the function is called `linspace` not `linespace`, and you are correct.  As per the documentation, "`y = linspace(a,b,n)`  generates a row vector `y` of `n` points linearly spaced between and including `a` and `b`", so the points do follow a `y = mx + c` relationship.  `a` is the start `y` value, `b` is the end `y` value, and  `n` is simply the number of points to sample, so it does not affect the linear relationship.

Comment: but  then  if i declare  like this,how it would be general  structure of program for which i use it?also  what is a importance of this declaration?

Comment: so for my case  let us  imagine that  y=m*x+c.that means that   y1=5 and  y4=10?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Think of it this way: if I call `linspace(1, 2, 2)`, the result I will get is a set of numbers between 1 (the first argument) and 2 (the second argument).  These numbers will be evenly spread out between 1 and 2.  Because the third argument is `2`, I only get 2 numbers: `[ 1 2 ]`.  If I change this to `3`, I get `3` numbers: `[ 1.0 1.5 2.0 ]`.  Now change it to `11`, and I get 11 numbers, evenly spread out between `1` and `2`.

Comment: that is what i am asking,for  [1.0 1.5 2.0]  we can see that these numbers are increasing   using  arithmetic progression,is it correct for  any number in the middle?

Comment: If you're asking, "will the result always be an arithmetic progression", the answer is yes.